# Where does a Fusion Drive store Time Machine local backups? Should I disable local backups?

Tags: macos, time-machine, ssd, core-storage, fusion-drive

Time Machine in OS X does store local backups (snapshots) on the local harddrive if you have Time Machine enabled.

Even if you backup regularly, the size of the local backups increases steadily. In a SSD-only setup I therefore disable local backups to decrease the write activity and used space of my SSD using:

```
sudo tmutil disablelocal
```

**Should I do this in a fusion drive as well?**